# How do I get git to use Textmate as my default editor?

Tags: git, bash, terminal, osx-lion, textmate

At the command-line, if I do `mate <filepath>` it opens up the right file for me in TextMate.

But when I do:

```
$ mate -v
open: invalid option -- v
Usage: open [-e] [-t] [-f] [-W] [-R] [-n] [-g] [-h] [-b <bundle identifier>] [-a <application>] [filenames] [--args arguments]
```

Also, when I do `git commit`, I see this:

```
$ git commit
error: cannot run mate: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor 'mate'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

My `~/.bashprofile` has these lines:

```
#Set Textmate as my default editor from the command-line
alias mate='open -a TextMate.app'

export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/mate -w"
```

And `~/.bashrc` has just this one:

```
alias mate='open -a TextMate.app'
```

**Edit 1**

My `~/.gitconfig` includes the following:

```
[user]
    name = My Name
    email = myemail@address.com
[core]
    editor = mate
[github]
    user = marcamillion
    token = 50e3iuaidsgadjkhwkjegakjhbsdkjb30432 (don't worry, this is fake)
```

Help!

Comment: And with export `EDITOR="mate"`, is this any better?

Comment: @VonC huh? Not sure I understand what you mean? What file should I be editing and what should I be writing/replacing?

Comment: @VonC if you mean if I try adding `export EDITOR="mate"` to my `.bashprofile`, then yes I just tried it and it hasn't worked. Do I have to close Terminal all together, or can I just close that Terminal session and re-open it? I have Rails server running in another Term session, so I would hate to have to close it. But if I need to, I can do that.

Comment: @marcamillion: opening a new session is sufficient

Comment: Yes,  I meant that, but the answers below are likely to be more accurate anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By adding the following to the core section in ~/.gitconfig

```
[core]
    editor = mate
```

Update:
Ok if it's already there then the issue is probably with textmate and not git.

Textmate 2:

In preferences there is a terminal tab and an install button
When you click on install mate will be in /usr/local/bin/mate and everything should work.

Textmate 1:

You need to create a symbolic link
http://manual.macromates.com/en/using_textmate_from_terminal.html

I have textmate 1 (I use vim now :)

```
ls -l `which mate`

lrwxr-xr-x  1 jameskyburz  staff  66 Jul  1  2011 /usr/local/bin/mate -> /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSup
```

ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate /usr/local/bin/mate

Comment: It's already there. Sorry, forgot to include that in my question. Will update it in a sec.

Answer (score 12):

> The editor used to edit the commit log message will be chosen from the
>   GIT_EDITOR environment variable, the core.editor configuration
>   variable, the VISUAL environment variable, or the EDITOR environment
>   variable (in that order).

Easy way to configure this, assuming the mate path is correct, is to run

```
git config --global core.editor "/usr/local/bin/mate -w"
```

Assuming, of course, that you can run `/usr/local/bin/mate -w`. Check that by running `/usr/local/bin/mate -w` with your local user. If it isn't found, you can use `which mate` to find it if it exists in your path at all - if it doesn't, I'd think you need to use the form you have in your alias (`open -a TextMate.app -w`).

Edit: incorporated comments into the answer.

Comment: Hrmm....great suggestion. So I tried running `/usr/local/bin/mate -w` and it returned a `-bash: /usr/local/bin/mate: No such file or directory`. Where else might TextMate be? How can I find it?

Comment: @marcamillion so that's your problem. try "which mate" to find it if it exists in your path.

Comment: @marcamillion if it doesn't, i'd think you need to use "open -a TextMate.app" that you have in your alias.

Comment: That was it! If you want to modify your answer, I will accept it.